# Split column value into separate columns based on length

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split, string-concatenation

I have multiple comma-separated values in one column with a size up to 20000 characters, and I want to split that column into one column but its based on character values 2000 (like into one new column it will take 2000 character and if length is grater than 2000 then its will be in second column like this).

When it's comma-separated value goes into first new column, then it should be meaningful like it should be based on `,` and up to 2000 characters only like this.

[image]

I have done from row level value to column level only but its should be 2000 character and based on comma

Could you please help me with this ?

Comment: Don't store such data this way to begin with. This breaks the most fundamental design rules and means you *can't* use any indexes to speed up querying. Never mind that querying becomes very hard. You might as well store the data into a file and split it in memory. In any case all supported SQL Server versions have `STRING_SPLIT`.

Comment: Without an example of the data and what you want to do it's impossible to help anyway, except to point to `STRING_SPLIT`. And repeat that storing comma separated or fixed width files in columns is a very bad idea. Clean and split the data *before* inserting it into the database if you want to query it. `bcp` and `BULK INSERT` can handle CSVs and fixed-width files

Comment: You can look for the index of first `,` after 2000, it will be `2000 + CHARINDEX(',',RIGHT(YOUR_COLUMN,LEN(YOUR_COLUMN) - 2000))`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos
 i have attached expected output but its split based on comma only . I want split it based on , and 2000 character in customDimesion1 then like this

Comment: You are trying to save a burning car by pushing it down the cliff into the water.... Storing massive data in CSV strings is a huge design flaw. And *name-numbered* columns (`col1, col2, col3 ...` are a clear hint for the need of a `1:n` related side table.

Comment: @siddhesh Post the *data*, not what you expect it to look like after processing. I already explained that parsing data is a job for the data loading job or script, not SQL. Why don't you use `bcp` or SSIS to load the file properly?

Comment: @siddhesh on the other hand, it looks like this is neither a CSV nor fixed table, but no table at all. Each value in that picture seems to be both an ID and a description. Clearly you only want the ID in each field, and the description should be called in a lookup table. The very name `Dimension` suggests these things are different dimensions in a star schema. This is far more complex than just splitting every 2K characters and on every comma and `__`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how we can split the column basis on length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

siddesh, although this question lacks of everything I want to point some things out and help you (as you are an unexperienced SO-user):

First I set up a *minimal reproducible exampel*. This is on you the next time.
I'll start with a declared table with some rows inserted.
We on SO can copy'n'paste this into our environment which makes it easy to answer.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourCSVString VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('1 this is long text, 2 some second fragment, 3 third fragment, 4 adfjksdahfljsadhfjhadlfhasdjks alsdjfsadhf k, 5 halksjfh asdkf ')
                      ,('1 this is other long text, 2 some second fragment to show that this works with tabular data, 3 again a third fragment, 4 adfjksdahfljsadhfjhadlfhasdjks alsdjfsadhf k, 5 halksjfh asdkf ');
```

--This is, what you **actually** need:

```
SELECT fkID = t.ID
      ,B.fragmentPosition
      ,B.fragmentContent 
      ,C.framgentLength
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT(N'["',REPLACE(t.YourCSVString,N',','","'),'"]')) A
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(A.[key],TRIM(A.[value]))) B(fragmentPosition,fragmentContent)
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(LEN(B.fragmentContent))) C(framgentLength);
```

The result should be stored within a physical table, where the `fkID` points to the ID of the original row and the `fragmentPosition` stores the order. `fkID` and `fragmentPosition` should be a combined unique key.

If you really want to do, what you are suggesting in your question (not recommended!) you can try something along this:

```
DECLARE @maxPerColumn INT=75;  --You can set the portion's max size, in your case 2000.

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT fkID = t.ID
          ,B.fragmentPosition
          ,B.fragmentContent 
          ,C.framgentLength
    FROM @tbl t
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT(N'["',REPLACE(t.YourCSVString,N',','","'),'"]')) A
    CROSS APPLY(VALUES(A.[key],TRIM(A.[value]))) B(fragmentPosition,fragmentContent)
    CROSS APPLY(VALUES(LEN(B.fragmentContent))) C(framgentLength)
)
,recCTE AS
(
    SELECT * 
          ,countPerColumn = 1
          ,columnCounter = 1
          ,sumLength = LEN(fragmentContent)
          ,growingString = CAST(fragmentContent AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
    FROM cte WHERE fragmentPosition=0

    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.fkID
          ,cte.fragmentPosition
          ,cte.fragmentContent
          ,cte.framgentLength
          ,CASE WHEN A.newSumLength>@maxPerColumn THEN 1 ELSE r.countPerColumn + 1 END
          ,r.columnCounter + CASE WHEN A.newSumLength>@maxPerColumn THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ,CASE WHEN A.newSumLength>@maxPerColumn THEN LEN(cte.fragmentContent) ELSE newSumLength END
          ,CASE WHEN A.newSumLength>@maxPerColumn THEN cte.fragmentContent ELSE CONCAT(r.growingString,N', ',cte.fragmentContent) END
    FROM cte
    INNER JOIN recCTE r ON r.fkID=cte.fkID AND r.fragmentPosition+1=cte.fragmentPosition 
    CROSS APPLY(VALUES(r.sumLength+LEN(cte.fragmentContent))) A(newSumLength)
)
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
       fkID
      ,growingString
      ,LEN(growingString)
FROM recCTE 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fkID,columnCounter ORDER BY countPerColumn DESC );
```

The result

```
fkID    pos Content
1       2   1 this is long text, 2 some second fragment, 3 third fragment
1       4   4 adfjksdahfljsadhfjhadlfhasdjks alsdjfsadhf k, 5 halksjfh asdkf
2       0   1 this is other long text
2       1   2 some second fragment to show that this works with tabular data
2       3   3 again a third fragment, 4 adfjksdahfljsadhfjhadlfhasdjks alsdjfsadhf k
2       4   5 halksjfh asdkf
```

The idea in short:

- The first cte does the splitting (as above)
- The recursive cte will iterate down the string and do the magic.
- The final `SELECT` uses a hack with `TOP 1 WITH TIES` together with an `ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)`. This will return the *highest* intermediate result only.

Hint: Don't do this...

**UPDATE**

Just for fun:

You can replace the final `SELECT` with this

```
,getPortions AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
           fkID
          ,fragmentPosition
          ,growingString
          ,LEN(growingString) portionLength
    FROM recCTE 
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fkID,columnCounter ORDER BY countPerColumn DESC )
)
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT fkID
          ,CONCAT(N'col',ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fkID ORDER BY fragmentPosition)) AS ColumnName
          ,growingString
    FROM getPortions
) t
PIVOT(MAX(growingString) FOR ColumnName IN(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)) p;
```

This will return exactly what you are asking for.

But - as said before - this is against all rules of *best practice*...